# Spring Data RESTful как сделать PUT

Tags: spring, rest

Не получается отработать PUT именно по {id}

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public List<Engine> update(@RequestBody final Engine engine){
    engineRepo.save(engine);
    return engineRepo.findAll();
}
```

Пока имеется вот это. Как изменить запись по "/{id}", не передавая его в теле запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Используя [@PathVariable](http://ru.java.wikia.com/wiki/@PathVariable)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public List<Engine> update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody final Engine engine){
    //Тут уже ваша бизнес логика.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

По мимо PathVariable, которая подхватит тебе нужный путь, помеченный в {}, ты можешь юзать PutMapping, чтобы не прописывать строчку, аля

`@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.PUT)`

```java
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public List<Engine> update(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody final Engine engine) {
    engineRepo.save(engine);
    return engineRepo.findAll();
}
```